# BackgroundColor Undefined

Tags: javascript, background-color

I don't understand why this isn't working. It says that the backgroundColor is undefined. I'm trying to get it to change color when clicked and the clicking works but it won't change colors.I think everything else works minus that, but hopefully someone on here can help me. Or if you have any suggestions on how to improve it that would be great.

```js
var squares=document.getElementsByClassName('squares');

for(var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    squares[0].addEventListener("click", changeColor);
}

function changeColor(event) {
    console.log("I work");
    event.style.backgroundColor=randomColor();

}

//the code below is fine if you're trying to debug it you've gone too far
function randomColor() {

    var randomRed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var randomGreen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var randomBlue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    //create the string that is the ‘random color’
    var randomColor = "rgb("+randomRed+","+randomGreen+","+randomBlue+")";

    return randomColor;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>FIX IT.</title>
    <style>
        .square {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: #000000;
            margin: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">
        <div class="square" onclick="changeColor(event)"></div>
        <div class="square" onclick="changeColor(event)"></div>
        <div class="square" onclick="changeColor(event)"></div>
        <div class="square" onclick="changeColor(event)"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `event` doesn't have a style property.

Answer (score 3):

It should be `event.target` when you set the `backgroundColor`.

Like this: `(event.target).style.backgroundColor=randomColor();`

`event.target` will refer to the `div` element which is clicked. That way you could add any style.

So, your changed code looks like this below:

```js
var squares=document.getElementsByClassName('squares');

for(var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    squares[0].addEventListener("click", changeColor);
}

function changeColor(event) {
    console.log("I work");
    (event.target).style.backgroundColor=randomColor();  // Observe the difference here

}

//the code below is fine if you're trying to debug it you've gone too far
function randomColor() {

    var randomRed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var randomGreen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var randomBlue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    //create the string that is the ‘random color’
    var randomColor = "rgb("+randomRed+","+randomGreen+","+randomBlue+")";

    return randomColor;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>FIX IT.</title>
    <style>
        .square {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: #000000;
            margin: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">
        <div class="square" onclick="changeColor(event)"></div>
        <div class="square" onclick="changeColor(event)"></div>
        <div class="square" onclick="changeColor(event)"></div>
        <div class="square" onclick="changeColor(event)"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this` to get the element that the event happened to.

```
function changeColor(event) {
  console.log("I work");
  this.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
}
```